# React functional stateless component, PureComponent, Component; what are the differences and when should we use what?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Came to know that from **React v15.3.0**, we have a new base class called **PureComponent** to extend with **PureRenderMixin** built-in. What I understand is that, under the hood this employs a shallow comparison of props inside `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Now we have 3 ways to define a React component:

1. Functional stateless component which doesn't extend any class
2. A component that extends `PureComponent` class
3. A normal component that extends `Component` class

Some time back we used to call stateless components as Pure Components, or even Dumb Components. Seems like the whole definition of the word "pure" has now changed in React.

Although I understand basic differences between these three, I am still not sure **when to choose what**. Also what are the performance impacts and trade-offs of each?

---

#### **Update**:

These are the question I expect to get clarified:

- Should I choose to define my simple components as functional (for the sake of simplicity) or extend `PureComponent` class (for performance sake)?
- Is the performance boost that I get a real trade-off for the
  simplicity I lost?
- Would I ever need to extend the normal `Component` class when I can always use `PureComponent` for better performance?

Answer (score 325, accepted):

### How do you decide, how do you choose between these three based on the purpose/size/props/behaviour of our components?

Extending from `React.PureComponent` or from `React.Component` with a custom `shouldComponentUpdate` method have performance implications. Using stateless functional components is an "architectural" choice and doesn't have any performance benefits out of the box (yet).

- For simple, presentational-only components that need to be easily reused, prefer stateless functional components. This way you're sure they are decoupled from the actual app logic, that they are dead-easy to test and that they don't have unexpected side effects. The exception is if for some reason you have *a lot* of them or if you really need to optimise their render method (as you can't define `shouldComponentUpdate` for a stateless functional component).
- Extend `PureComponent` if you know your output depends on simple props/state ("simple" meaning no nested data structures, as PureComponent performs a shallow compare) AND you need/can get some performance improvements.
- Extend `Component` and implement your own `shouldComponentUpdate` if you need some performance gains by performing custom comparison logic between next/current props and state. For example, you can quickly perform a deep comparison using lodash#isEqual:

  ```
  class MyComponent extends Component {
      shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps, nextState) {
          return !_.isEqual(this.props, nextProps) || !_.isEqual(this.state, nextState);
      }
  }
  ```

Also, implementing your own `shouldComponentUpdate` or extending from `PureComponent` are optimizations, and as usual you should start looking into that only if you have performance issues ([avoid premature optimizations](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization)). 
As a rule of thumb, I always try to do these optimisations after the application is in a working state, with most of the features already implemented. It's a lot easier to focus on performance problems when they actually get in the way.

### More details

**Functional stateless components:**

These are defined just using a function. Since there's no internal state for a stateless component, the output (what's rendered) only depends on the props given as input to this function.

Pros:

- Simplest possible way of defining a component in React. If you don't need to manage any state, why bother with classes and inheritance? One of the main differences between a function and a class is that with the function you are sure the output depends only on the input (not on any history of the previous executions).
- Ideally in your app you should aim to have as many stateless components as possible, because that normally means you moved your logic outside of the view layer and moved it to something like redux, which means you can test your real logic without having to render anything (much easier to test, more reusable, etc.).

Cons:

- No lifecycle methods. You don't have a way to define `componentDidMount` and other friends. Normally you do that within a parent component higher in the hierarchy so you can turn all the children into stateless ones.
- No way to manually control when a re-render is needed, since you can't define `shouldComponentUpdate`. A re-render happens every time the component receives new props (no way to shallow compare, etc.). In the future, React could automatically optimise stateless components, for now there's some libraries you can use. Since stateless components are just functions, basically it's the classic problem of "function memoization".
- Refs are not supported: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4936

**A component that extends PureComponent class VS A normal component that extends Component class:**

React used to have a `PureRenderMixin` you could attach to a class defined using `React.createClass` syntax. The mixin would simply define a `shouldComponentUpdate` performing a shallow comparison between the next props and the next state to check if anything there changed. If nothing changes, then there's no need to perform a re-render.

If you want to use the ES6 syntax, you can't use mixins. So for convenience React introduced a `PureComponent` class you can inherit from instead of using `Component`. `PureComponent` just implements `shouldComponentUpdate` in the same way of the `PureRendererMixin`. It's mostly a convenience thing so you don't have to implement it yourself, as a shallow comparison between current/next state and props is probably the most common scenario that can give you some quick performance wins.

Example:

```
class UserAvatar extends Component {
    render() {
       return <div><img src={this.props.imageUrl} /> {{ this.props.username }} </div>
    }
}
```

As you can see the output depends on `props.imageUrl` and `props.username`. If in a parent component you render `<UserAvatar username="fabio" imageUrl="http://foo.com/fabio.jpg" />` with the same props, React would call `render` every time, even if the output would be exactly the same. Remember though that React implements dom diffing, so the DOM would not be actually updated. Still, performing the dom diffing can be expensive, so in this scenario it would be a waste.

If the `UserAvatar` component extends `PureComponent` instead, a shallow compare is performed. And because props and nextProps are the same, `render` will not be called at all.

**Notes on the definition of "pure" in React:**

In general, a "pure function" is a function that evaluates always to the same result given the same input. The output (for React, that's what is returned by the `render` method) doesn't depend on any history/state and it doesn't have any side-effects (operations that change the "world" outside of the function).

In React, stateless components are not necessarily pure components according to the definition above if you call "stateless" a component that never calls `this.setState` and that doesn't use `this.state`.

In fact, in a `PureComponent`, you can still perform side-effects during lifecycle methods. For example you could send an ajax request inside `componentDidMount` or you could perform some DOM calculation to dynamically adjust the height of a div within `render`.

The "Dumb components" definition has a more "practical" meaning (at least in my understanding): a dumb component "gets told" what to do by a parent component via props, and doesn't know how to do things but uses props callbacks instead.

Example of a "smart" `AvatarComponent`:

```
class AvatarComponent extends Component {
    expandAvatar () {
        this.setState({ loading: true });
        sendAjaxRequest(...).then(() => {
            this.setState({ loading: false });
        });
    }        

    render () {
        <div onClick={this.expandAvatar}>
            <img src={this.props.username} />
        </div>
    }
}
```

Example of a "dumb" `AvatarComponent`:

```
class AvatarComponent extends Component {
    render () {
        <div onClick={this.props.onExpandAvatar}>
            {this.props.loading && <div className="spinner" />}
            <img src={this.props.username} />
        </div>
    }
}
```

In the end I would say that "dumb", "stateless" and "pure" are quite different concepts that can sometimes overlap, but not necessarily, depending mostly on your use case.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer and the knowledge you've shared. But my real question is **when should we choose what?**. For the same example you mentioned in your answer, how should I define it? Should it be functional stateless component (if so why?), or extending PureComponent (why?) or extend Component class (again why?). How do you decide, how do you choose between these three based on the **purpose/size/props/behaviour** of our components?

Comment: No problem. For the functional stateless component, there is a pros/cons list that I you can consider to decide if that would be a good fit. Does that answer you first point? I'm going to try to address the choice question a bit more.

Comment: Indeed that was very helpful. Please see the question again, I have updated it with the questions that I expect to get clarified.

Comment: thanks, see the last section I added to my updated answer.

Comment: Functional components are always re-rendered when the parent component gets updated, even if they don't use `props` at all. [example](https://codepen.io/pumbo/pen/NvBqRM).

Comment: @AlexM Your example is a little confusing because you're using props in your `FunctionalComponent` as outputs `props.children`. To make the example more clear, just remove `props` from the function and don't render `props.children` inside. The `console.log` still fires, even though the comp. cannot accept any props whatsoever.

Comment: This is one of the most comprehensive answers I have read in quite some time. Great work.
One comment about the very first sentence: When extending `PureComponent`, you should not implement `shouldComponentUpdate()`. You should see a warning if you do this actually.

Comment: The most important thing that i noticed is PureComponent. I will go there. Because it has feature 'shallowCompare'

Comment: As of React 16, there are now performance advantages of function components over regular (i.e. `Component`, not `PureComponent`) class components. See https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/639. And for cases where all props are primitives rather than objects/arrays that React would deeply compare by default, I think a function component would now be faster than `PureComponent` (if I understand correctly).

Comment: I don't think this part of the answer makes sense: "Extend PureComponent if you know your output depends on simple props/state ("simple" meaning no nested data structures". That might be the safest usage of `PureComponent`, but also the least useful, since no deep comparison is done by default for primitive props anyway.

Comment: For real performance gains you should try to use `PureComponent` for components that DO have nested object/array properties. Of course you have to be aware of what's happening. If I understand correctly, if you're not mutating props/state directly (which React tries to prevent you from doing with warnings) or via an external library, then you should be fine using `PureComponent` instead of `Component` pretty much everywhere...with the exception of very simple components where it can  actually be faster NOT to use it - see https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14418576

Comment: Why AvatarComponent is not a PureComponent?

Comment: "You don't have a way to define componentDidMount and other friends." - This is no longer true, you can use hooks, specifically the useEffect hook.

Answer (score 28):

i am not a genius over react, but from my understanding we can use each component in following situations

1. **Stateless component --**  these are the component which doesn't have life-cycle so those components should be used in rendering repeat element of parent component such as rendering the text list which just displays the information and doesn't have any actions to perform.
2. **Pure component --** these are the items which have life-cycle and they will always return the same result when a specific set of props is given. Those components can be used when displaying a list of results or a specific object data which doesn't have complex child elements and used to perform operations which only impact itself. such a displaying list of user cards or list of products cards( basic product info) and only action user can perform is click to view detail page or add to cart.
3. **Normal Components or Complex Components --** I used term complex component because those are usually the page level components and consists lot of children components and since each of child can behave in its own unique way so you can't be 100% sure that it will render the same result on given state. As I said usually these should be used as container components

Comment: This approach could work, but you could be missing out on big performance gains. Using `PureComponent` in root-level components and components near the top of your hierarchy is usually where you would see the biggest performance gains. Of course you do need to avoid mutating props and state directly for pure components to work correctly, but mutating objects directly is an anti-pattern in React anyhow.

Answer (score 6):

- `React.Component` is the default "normal" component.  You declare them using the `class` keyword and `extends React.Component`.  Think of them as a class, with lifecycles methods, event handlers and whatever methods.
- `React.PureComponent` is a `React.Component` that implements `shouldComponentUpdate()` with a function that does a shallow comparison of its `props` and `state`.  You have to use `forceUpdate()` if you know the component has props or state nested data that changed and you want to re-render.  So they're not great if you need components to re-render when arrays or objects you pass as props or set in your state change.
- Functional components are ones that don't have lifecycle functions.  They're supposedly stateless, but they're so nice and clean that we now have hooks (since React 16.8) so you can still have a state.  So I guess they're just "clean components".

Answer (score 0):

A pure component in React is a component that only re-renders when its props change. It helps optimize performance by preventing unnecessary re-renders when the component's props remain the same.
Here's a simple example:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';

class Greeting extends PureComponent {

    render() {
      return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}!</h1>;
    }
}

const App = () => {

    const name = "John Doe";
    
    return (
      <div>
        <Greeting name={name} />
      </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

In this example, we have a `Greeting` component that receives a name prop and displays a greeting message with the name. The Greeting component is a pure component because it only relies on its props and doesn't have any internal state.
The App component renders the `Greeting` component with a specific name prop value, which is 'John Doe' in this case. Since the `Greeting` component is a pure component, it won't re-render unnecessarily as long as the name prop remains the same.
Pure components are helpful in scenarios where you want to prevent unnecessary re-renders of components that rely only on their props

To learn more [here](https://fullstackindepth.com/)