# shouldComponentUpdate in function components

Tags: reactjs

I have a question regarding React's `shouldComponentUpdate` (when not overwritten). I do prefer pure, function components, but I am afraid that it updates every time, even though props/state did not change. 
So I am considering using the PureComponent class instead.

My question regarding that:
Do function components have the same `shouldComponentUpdate` check as PureComponents? Or does it update every time?

Comment: update everytime a parent has changed?

Comment: **TLDR**: [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In React, functional components are stateless and they do not have lifecycle methods. **Stateless components are an elegant way of writing React components without much code in our bundle.** But internally, Stateless components are wrapped in a class without any optimizations currently applied. That means both stateless and stateful components has the same code path internally (although we define them differently).

But in the future React may optimize stateless components as said it here:

> In the future, we’ll also be able to make performance optimizations
>   specific to these components by avoiding unnecessary checks and memory
>   allocations. [[ More reading... ]](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#stateless-functional-components)

#### `shouldComponentUpdate`

This is where you we can apply our custom optimizations and avoid unnecessary re-rendering of components. The usage of this method with different types of components are explained below:

- **Functional Stateless components**

  As said before, stateless components do not have life cycle methods thus we cannot optimize them using `shouldComponentUpdate`. But they are already optimized in a different way, they have much simpler and elegant code structure and costs less bytes than a component with all life-cycle hooks.
- **extend React.PureComponent**

  From **React v15.3.0**, we have a new base class called **`PureComponent`** 
  to extend with **`PureRenderMixin`** built-in. Under the hood this employs a shallow comparison of current props/state with next props/state within a `shouldComponentUpdate`.

  That said, we still cannot rely on `PureComponent` class to get our components optimized to the level we want. This anomaly case happens if we have props with `Object` types (arrays, dates, plain objects). This is because we have this problem when comparing objects:

  ```
  const obj1 = { id: 1 };
  const obj2 = { id: 1 };
  console.log(obj1 === obj2); // prints false
  ```

  Hence a shallow comparison won't suffice to determine whether things have changed or not. But use `PureComponent` class if your props are just string, number, boolean.. and not objects. Also use it if you do not want to implement your own custom optimizations.
- **extend React.Component**

  Consider the above example; if we know that the objects have changed if the `id` has changed, then we can implement our own custom optimization by comparing `obj1.id === obj2.id`. That is where we can `extend` our normal `Component` base class and use `shouldComponentUpdate` to do the comparison of specific keys by ourselves.

Comment: So would it be safe to say that it is almost always more efficient to use a stateless component versus a regular component with shouldComponentUpdate implemented?

Comment: Please see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40703675/react-functional-stateless-component-purecomponent-component-what-are-the-dif).

Comment: It's probably worth noting that functional components are no longer necessarily stateless, thanks to [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

Answer (score 108):

A functional component will rerender every time the parent renders it, no matter if the props have changed or not.

However, using the `React.memo` high order component it is actually possible for functional components to get the same `shouldComponentUpdate` check which is used in `PureComponent` https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

You can simply wrap your functional component in `React.memo` on export like shown here.

So

```
const SomeComponent = (props) => (<div>HI</div>)
export default SomeComponent
```

Could instead be

```
const SomeComponent = (props) => (<div>HI</div>)
export default React.memo(SomeComponent)
```

**Example**

The following example show how this affects rerenders

The parent component is just a regular functional component. It is using the new [react hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) to handle some state updates.

It just have some `tick` state which only serves the purpose of giving some clues on how often we rerender a prop, while it forces a rerender of the parent component twice a second.

Further we have a `clicks` state which tell how often we have clicked the button. This is what the prop we send to the children. **Hence they should ONLY rerender if the number of clicks changes if we use `React.memo`**

Now notice that we have two different kind of children. One wrapped in `memo` and one which is not. `Child` which is not wrapped, will rerender every time the parent rerenders. `MemoChild` which is wrapped, will only rerender when the clicks property changes.

```
const Parent = ( props ) => {
  // Ticks is just some state we update 2 times every second to force a parent rerender
  const [ticks, setTicks] = React.useState(0);
  setTimeout(() => setTicks(ticks + 1), 500);
  // The ref allow us to pass down the updated tick without changing the prop (and forcing a rerender)
  const tickRef = React.useRef();
  tickRef.current = ticks;

  // This is the prop children are interested in
  const [clicks, setClicks] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Parent Rendered at tick {tickRef.current} with clicks {clicks}.</h2>
      <button 
        onClick={() => setClicks(clicks + 1)}>
        Add extra click
      </button>
      <Child tickRef={tickRef} clicks={clicks}/>
      <MemoChild tickRef={tickRef} clicks={clicks}/>
    </div>
  );
};

const Child = ({ tickRef, clicks }) => (
  <p>Child Rendered at tick {tickRef.current} with clicks {clicks}.</p>
);

const MemoChild = React.memo(Child);
```

Live Example (also [on CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ywJxzV)):

```js
console.log("HI");

const Parent = ( props ) => {
  const [ticks, setTicks] = React.useState(0);
  const tickRef = React.useRef();
  tickRef.current = ticks;
  const [clicks, setClicks] = React.useState(0);
  
  setTimeout(() => setTicks(ticks + 1), 500);
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Parent Rendered at tick {tickRef.current} with clicks {clicks}.</h2>
      <button 
        onClick={() => setClicks(clicks + 1)}>
        Add extra click
      </button>
      <Child tickRef={tickRef} clicks={clicks}/>
      <MemoChild tickRef={tickRef} clicks={clicks}/>
    </div>
  );
};

const Child = ({ tickRef, clicks }) => (
  <p>Child Rendered at tick {tickRef.current} with clicks {clicks}.</p>
);

const MemoChild = React.memo(Child);


ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: *Further explanation to this nice answer*: The `tickRef` is the same Object throughout the "life" of the parent component (that's how `useRef` works), and only the `current` property is changed. The trick, is that `memo` only does shallow comparison for the props, so it is not aware that `tickRef` has a property which keeps changing.

Comment: So then it's safe to say that deep prop changes don't trigger re-renders in the child component either. That's one way to trick the component into not re-rendering. Very simple too.

Answer (score 17):

Another approach is to use [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) to update values only when watched ones are updated:

```
const memoizedValue = useMemo(() => computeExpensiveValue(a, b), [a, b]);
```

In case of objects there's an option of using state hook to cache the value of interested variable, after making sure it's updated. Eg by using `lodash`:

```
const [fooCached, setFooCached]: any = useState(null);

if (!_.isEqual(fooCached, foo)) {
  setFooCached(foo);
}). 

const showFoo = useMemo(() => {
    return <div>Foo name: { foo.name }</div>
}, [fooCached]);
```

Comment: Yeah, this question was > 2 years ago, but I like this answer today. I believe any hook that takes deps can do this not just useMemo. useEffect with same syntax:

`useEffect(() => computeExpensiveValue(a, b), [a, b]);`

Answer (score 13):

### Specific Prop Comparison

There are many great answers here already. I just would like to add an example where you want to specifically compare a prop (instead of all props) and decide to re-render based on that.

#### Example

Below is a `Header` component that I wanted to re-render only when `heading` string prop is changed.

```js
import React from 'react'

const Header = ({ heading }) => {
  console.log('Header')
  return (
    <h2 className='bg-gray-300 text-gray-800 text-center py-6 px-8 rounded-md text-xl font-extrabold'>
      {heading}
    </h2>
  )
}


const areEqual = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  if (prevProps.heading === nextProps.heading) {
    return true                                    // donot re-render
  }
  return false                                     // will re-render
}


export default React.memo(Header, areEqual)
```

The key thing about return value of `areEqual` is:

- `return true` => does not re-render
- `return false` => will re-render

I got this from official docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

Comment: If you are still following this. Your answer saved me! My team was stuck at this issue for quite long. This is the exact solution we wanted! Thanks a Ton!