# shouldComponentUpdate equivalent for functional component, to ignore state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, reactive-programming

My code has a component that takes both props and has its own internal state.
The component should rerender ONLY when its props change. State changes should NOT trigger a rerender.
This behaviour can be implemented with a class based component and a custom `shouldComponentUpdate` function.
However, this would be the first class based component in the codebase. Everything is done with functional components and hooks.
Therefore I would like to know whether it is possible to code the desired functionality with functional components.

After a few answers that didn't approach the real problem, I think I have to reformulate my question. Here is a minimal example with two components:

- Inner takes a prop and has state. This is the component in question. It must not rerender after state changes. Prop changes should trigger a rerender.
- Outer is a wrapper around inner. It has no meaning in the scope of this question and is only there to give props to Inner and to simulate prop changes.

To demonstrate the desired functionality I have implemented Inner with a class based component. [A live version of this code can be found on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-morse-i7r3t). How can I migrate it to a functional component:

`Inner.tsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

interface InnerProps{outerNum:number}
interface InnerState{innerNum:number}

export default class Inner extends Component<InnerProps, InnerState> {
    state = {innerNum:0};

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps:InnerProps, nextState:InnerState){
        return this.props != nextProps;
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={()=>{
                this.setState({innerNum: Math.floor(Math.random()*10)})
            }}>
                {`${this.props.outerNum}, ${this.state.innerNum}`}
            </button>
        )
    }
}
```

Outer.tsx:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Inner from "./Inner";

export default function Outer() {
  const [outerState, setOuterState] = useState(1);

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setOuterState(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
        }}
      >
        change outer state
      </button>
      <Inner outerNum={outerState}></Inner>
    </>
  );
}
```

[The official docs say](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate) to wrap the component in `React.memo`. But this doesn't seem to work for preventing rerenders on state change. It only applies to prop changes.

I have tried to make `React.memo` work. You can see a version of the code with both Outer and Inner being functional components [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-albattani-sk30l).

**Related questions:**

[How to use shouldComponentUpdate with React Hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56297351/how-to-use-shouldcomponentupdate-with-react-hooks?rq=1) : This question only deals with prop changes. The accepted answer advises to use `React.memo`

[shouldComponentUpdate in function components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40909902/shouldcomponentupdate-in-function-components) : This question predates stateful functional components. The accepted answer explains how functional components don't need `shouldComponentUpdate` since they are stateless.

Comment: React.memo: "This method only exists as a performance optimization. Do not rely on it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs." - Could you present us the case where you might need it? Maybe we can suggest other solutions such as introducing the `key` property. But its hard to reason about the problem without the case itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React is by design driven by setState -> re-render loop. Props change is in fact a setState somewhere in parent components. If you don't want the setState to trigger a re-render, then why in the first place use it?

You can pull in a `const state = useRef({}).current` to store your internal state instead.

```
function InnerFunc(props) {
  const state = useRef({ innerNum: 0 }).current;
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        state.innerNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
      }}
    >
      {`${props.outerNum}, ${state.innerNum}`}
    </button>
  );
}
```

---

That said, it's still a valid question to ask: "how to implement shouldComponentUpdate in a react hook fashion?" Here's the solution:

```
function shouldComponentUpdate(elements, predicate, deps) {
  const store = useRef({ deps: [], elements }).current
  const shouldUpdate = predicate(store.deps)
  if (shouldUpdate) {
    store.elements = elements
  }
  store.deps = deps
  return store.elements
}

// Usage:

function InnerFunc(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ innerNum: 0 })
  const elements = (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        setState({ innerNum: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) });
      }}
    >
      {`${props.outerNum}, ${state.innerNum}`}
    </button>
  );

  return shouldComponentUpdate(elements, (prevDeps) => {
    return prevDeps[0] !== props
  }, [props, state])
}
```

Noted that it's impossible to prevent a re-render cycle when `setState` is called, the above hook merely makes sure the re-rendered result stays the same as prev rendered result.

Answer (score 1):

React memo do not stop state changes

> React.memo only checks for prop changes. If your function component
>   wrapped in React.memo has a useState or useContext Hook in its
>   implementation, it will still rerender when state or context change.

Ref:-  https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

Answer (score 0):

Your `Inner` component depends on the property `num` of the `Outer` component, [**you can't** prevent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) it from rendering on property change as `React.memo` makes properties comparison:

```
// The default behaviour is shallow comparison between previous and current render properties.
const areEqual = (a, b) => a.num === b.num;
export default React.memo(Inner, areEqual);
```

By memoizing the `Inner` component and removing the `num` dependency, it won't render on `Outer` rendering, see sandbox attached.

```
export default function Outer() {
  const [outerState, setOuterState] = useState(1);

  return (
    <>
      ...
    // v Inner is memoized and won't render on `outerState` change.
      <Inner />
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit clever-silence-6xigt]

---

If you want to implement `shouldComponentUpdate` with hooks you can try:

```
const [currState] = useState();
// shouldUpdateState your's custom function to compare and decide if update state needed
setState(prevState => {
  if(shouldUpdateState(prevState,currState)) {
    return currState;
  }
  return prevState;
});
```

Comment: No, rerendering on prop changes is ok. I want to prevent rerenders when the inner state changes.

Comment: When inner state change the parent wont render, what you want to prevent? The inner render?

Comment: Yes, I want to prevent rerenders of the inner component, after setstate has been called, also on the inner component.

Comment: Did you see the sandbox? The inner component does not render, on outer setState.

Comment: If you dont want the inner to render so dont call set state :\

Comment: What I'm trying to do is having a component that doesn't rerender when setstate is called. This is perfectly possible with class based components, I would like to see an implementation with functional components (since the app uses hooks everywhere).

Comment: If you talking about shouldComponentUpdate there are enough questions like this on SO

Comment: I am aware of shouldComponentUpdate and I did search SO before posting this. While there are questions that seem to be exact duplicates they either: only deal with prop changes, or predate stateful components.

Comment: I will add an example of how to implement shouldComponentUpdate

Answer (score -2):

you should use the event that provide the browser and capture in the function before setState, like this

```
function setState = (e) =>{ //the e is the event that give you the browser
//changing the state
e.preventDefault();
}
```