Using Recoil, Why are other components also re-rendering when only 01 component is changing the state?
First of all, thank you for your time in going through my query and sharing your valuable tips and answers.
I have implemented an Amazon Checkout Page using React and Recoil.
Everything works as expected but the application is not behaving as expected by using Recoil.
That is, only that component should re-render that changes the state.
My Main focus while implementing this mini assignment, was on the Recoil Implementation, and did not use Routing so Layout was also not used (Header, Footer).
Flow:-
->Get data from the backend (array of cartItems) and store it in an atom
(I do not want to call 'n' calls to backend for 'n' items so get an array of todos)
What I did:-
->Use selectorFamily to retrieve/set a particular item.
->use selectorFamily to retrieve/set derived state of a particular item
Problem:-
->cartItem.jsx component is subscribing to the itemQuantity of the specific item by id
but why are all the other component are re-rendering when quantity is updated (Header,Footer,Other cartItem, and AmazonCheckout)
I know AmazonCheckout is dependent on cartItems array which is coming from the main atom but why is the other cartItem component re-rendered?
My Solution (Tentative):- Use React.memo in all the other components (Header,Footer, and cartItem.jsx) ???
Is there any other way to implement this Flow??
Github repo link:- https://github.com/pradeep652227/reactjs-cohort3.0/tree/main/02_assignment_amazonkart
cartItems-Atom.js:-
import { atom, selector, selectorFamily } from "recoil";

// Atom to store all todos as a dictionary
export const cartItemsAtom = atom({
    key: "cartItemsAtom",
    default: selector({
        key: "cartItemsSelector",
        get: async () => {
            const response = await getItemsFromBackend();
            // Transforming the array into an object by id
            return response.reduce((acc, todo) => {
                acc[todo.id] = todo;
                return acc;
            }, {});
        }   
    })
});

// SelectorFamily to retrieve a specific item by id
export const cartItemsSelectorFamily = selectorFamily({
    key: "cartItemsSelectorFamily",
    get: (id) => ({ get }) => {
        const items = get(cartItemsAtom);
        return items[id] || { id: '', title: '', price: '', quantity: 0, isInStock: false, img: '' };
    },
    set: (id) => ({ set, get }, newValue) => {
        const items = get(cartItemsAtom);
        set(cartItemsAtom, { ...items, [id]: newValue });
    }
});

// SelectorFamily to retrieve the in-stock status of an item
export const isInStockSelectorFamily = selectorFamily({
    key: "isInStockSelectorFamily",
    get: (id) => ({ get }) => {
        const item = get(cartItemsSelectorFamily(id));
        return item.isInStock || false;
    }
});

// SelectorFamily to manage the quantity of each item
export const itemQuantitySelectorFamily = selectorFamily({
    key: "itemQuantitySelectorFamily",
    get: (id) => ({ get }) => {
        const item = get(cartItemsSelectorFamily(id));
        return item?.quantity || 0;
    },
    set: (id) => ({ get, set }, newQuantity) => {
        const isInStock=get(isInStockSelectorFamily(id));
        if(!isInStock){
            alert('Item is Out Of Stock');
            return;
        }

        if(newQuantity>=0){
            const item = get(cartItemsSelectorFamily(id));
            // Ensure immutability by creating a new object
            const updatedItem = { ...item, quantity: newQuantity };
            set(cartItemsSelectorFamily(id), updatedItem);
        }
    }
});

export const deleteCartItemSelectorFamily = selectorFamily({
    key: "deleteCartItemSelectorFamily",
    set: (id) => ({ get, set }) => {
        const items = get(cartItemsAtom);
        if (items[id]) {
            //preserved immutability
            const newItems = { ...items };
            delete newItems[id];
            set(cartItemsAtom, newItems);
        }
    }
});

async function getItemsFromBackend() {
    return [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: "FUR JADEN 40L Weekender Travel Laptop Backpack with Anti Theft Pocket, Organizer, 15.6 Inch Padded Laptop Sleeve and Dual Hand",
            price: 369,
            quantity: 2,
            isInStock: true,
            img: ""
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: "Testing",
            price: 2069,
            quantity: 2,
            isInStock: false,
            img: ""
        }
    ]
}

AmazonCheckout.jsx
import { useRef,useMemo } from "react";
import { Header,Footer, Container, CartItem } from "../Components/imports-components";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
import { useRecoilValue } from "recoil";
import { cartItemsAtom } from "../store/imports-store";

export default function AmazonCheckout(){
    const checkoutIdRef=useRef(nanoid());
    const cartItems=useRecoilValue(cartItemsAtom);
    const cartItemsArray=useMemo(()=>Object.values(cartItems),[cartItems]);
    // const totalPrice=useMemo(()=>cartItemsArray.reduce((acc,item)=>acc+(parseFloat(item.price)*parseFloat(item.quantity)),0),
    //                         [cartItemsArray]);

    // const totalItems=useMemo(()=>cartItemsArray.reduce((acc,item)=>acc+parseInt(item.quantity),0),[cartItemsArray])
    
    //For test purpose, used hardCoded values
    const totalPrice=22222;
    const totalItems=4;

    console.log('Amazon Checkout Component');

    return(<>
            <Header/>
            <Container className="py-4 bg-slate-200 !max-w-full">
                <div id={`checkoutBox ${checkoutIdRef.current}`} className="flex flex-wrap md:flex-nowrap justify-between gap-4">
                    <div data-unique="checkout-leftPart" className="bg-white rounded-xl p-4">
                        <h1 className="text-2xl font-semibold mb-2">Shopping Cart</h1>
                        <div data-unique="items" className="space-y-4">
                            {
                                cartItemsArray.map(item=><CartItem key={item.id} id={item.id}
                                 />)
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div data-unique="checkout-rightPart" className="bg-white rounded-xl p-4 h-fit w-max">
                        <h1 className="text-2xl font-semibold">Order Summary</h1>
                        <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-between">
                            <span>Items ({totalItems})</span>
                            <span>TotalPrice: {totalPrice}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </Container>
            <Footer />
        </>
    );
}

cart-item.jsx
import { useRef,useState } from 'react';
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
import {Button} from '../Reusables/imports-reusables';
import { useRecoilState, useSetRecoilState,useRecoilValue } from 'recoil';
import { deleteCartItemSelectorFamily, isInStockSelectorFamily, itemQuantitySelectorFamily,cartItemsSelectorFamily } from '../store/atoms/cartItems-Atom';

export default function CartItem({id}){
console.log('CartITem component');

const idRef=useRef(nanoid());
const {title,price}=useRecoilValue(cartItemsSelectorFamily(id));
const isInStock=useRecoilValue(isInStockSelectorFamily(id));
const [itemQuantity,setItemQuantity]=useRecoilState(itemQuantitySelectorFamily(id));
const setDeleteCartItem=useSetRecoilState(deleteCartItemSelectorFamily(id));

const quantityBtnClasses='bg-slate-300 rounded-md text-xl px-3 py-1';

    return(

        <div id={`cart-item ${idRef.current}`} className='flex flex-wrap md:flex-nowrap justify-between gap-4 px-4'>
        <div data-unique="cart-left-part" className='flex flex-wrap md:flex-nowrap space-x-2'>
            <div data-unique="cart-item-image" className="bg-slate-300" style={{"height":"90px",width:"90px"}}>
            </div>
            <div data-unique="cart-item-details">
                <span role="heading" data-unique="cart-item-heading" 
                className='text-xl font-semibold block'>
                    {title}
                </span>
                <span data-unique="cart-item-status" 
                className={`${isInStock?"text-green-500":"text-red-500"} block`}>
                    {isInStock?"In Stock":"Out Of Stock"}
                </span>
                <div data-unique="cart-item-incr-decr" className='space-x-2'>
                    <Button className={quantityBtnClasses} onClick={increaseQuantity}>+</Button>
                    <span data-unique="cart-item-quantity">{itemQuantity}</span>
                    <Button className={`${quantityBtnClasses}`} onClick={decreaseQuantity}>-</Button>
                    <Button className='bg-transparent 
                    text-blue-500 font-semibold hover:text-blue-700 duration-200'
                    onClick={()=>setDeleteCartItem()}
                    >Delete
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <span data-unique="cart-item-price" className=''>Rs. {price}</span>

    </div>
    
    )

    
function increaseQuantity(){
    setItemQuantity(q=>q+1);
}

function decreaseQuantity(){
    setItemQuantity(q=>q-1);
}

}


Yes, memo is the way. See the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40909902 (the question itself is not an exact duplicate, but the answers all totally apply)

@PeterB sir, thank you for confirming my tentative solution. But, what is the use of using Recoil if we need to manually wrap all the other components in React.memo?

Sorry, I don't know what Recoil is and I have no idea if or how that could have an effect on this.
