# Getting 'undefined is not an object' when calling navigation prop methods in react native navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm having trouble calling react navigation methods from custom components outside of my original screens, specifically the one I'm working on right now is trying to call goBack() in a back arrow of a custom header component I made (code below). The error message I'm getting when I click the back arrow is:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation.goBack')
```

Here is the code:

```
// HeaderText.js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { Icon } from 'expo';

export class HeaderText extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const needsBackButton = this.props.backIcon;
    if (needsBackButton) {
        return(
            <View style={[styles.headerStyle,styles.buttonHeaderStyle]}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()} style={styles.backButtonStyles}><Icon.Ionicons size={25} style={{ color: '#fff', fontWeight: 'bold' }} name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? `ios-arrow-back` : 'md-arrow-back'} /></TouchableOpacity>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{this.props.headerText}</Text>
                <View style={styles.emptyViewStyles} />
            </View>
            );
    } else {
        return(
            <View style={styles.headerStyle}>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{this.props.headerText}</Text>
            </View>
            );
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the screen I'm putting that HeaderText component in:

```
// SubmitReferralScreen.js
import React from 'react';
import {
  Image,
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  ImageBackground
} from 'react-native';

import { MonoText } from '../../components/general/StyledText';
import { HeaderText } from '../../components/general/HeaderText';
import { HomeScreenContainer } from '../../components/homeScreen/HomeScreenContainer';
import { IconButton } from '../../components/general/IconButton';
import { StatusInfo } from '../../constants/StatusInfo';
import SvgUri from 'react-native-svg-uri';

export default class SubmitReferralScreen extends React.Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, width: '100%',justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <ImageBackground source={require('../../assets/images/background.png')} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: 'background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',}}>
            <HeaderText backIcon='true' headerText='New Referral' />
              <Text>Submit referral here!</Text>
          </ImageBackground>
        </View>
    );
  }

}
```

And here is my Stack Navigator for the referral Screens:

```
// MainTabNavigator.js
const ReferralStack = createStackNavigator({
  Referrals: ReferralScreen,
  MakeReferral: SubmitReferralScreen,
});
```

I've looked at this StackOverflow answer: [Getting undefined is not an object evaluating _this.props.navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45226391/getting-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-this-props-navigation) 
And the answer there was to put only `navigation.navigate(YourScreen)`. I tried that, and the error I got said "cannot find variable navigation".
**How can I call navigation props from custom react native components?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default only screen components are provided with the `navigation` prop. You can either use library provided ways of hooking up arbitrary components to the navigation state, or you can pass navigation as a prop manually.

**Option #1. Using `withNavigation`:**
React navigation exports a higher-order component through which you can inject the navigation props into any component you want. To do this, you can do something like:

1. Don't immediately export the `HeaderText` component class (remove `export` from that line)
2. At the bottom of that file add `export default withNavigation( HeaderText );`

or if you don't want to use a default export and keep it as a named export, instead do:

```
const NavigationConnected = withNavigation( HeaderText );
export { NavigationConnected as HeaderText };
```

**Option #2. Passing `navigation` as prop**: In your `SubmitReferralScreen` component you can simply pass `this.props.navigation` as a prop to the `HeaderText` component like: `<HeaderText navigation={ this.props.navigation } />`

Comment: Awesome, I used option 1!!! The problem was, I was doing it like this: `export withNavigation( HeaderText );` and not the way you did it, that works!!!!

Comment: Great solutions! I used Option #1 because I have lot of child components and did not want to set navigation props 2-3 times after each other.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `navigation` prop didn't found where is the navigation's value prop from the parent. Better you make HeaderText component using regular arrow function, like this;

```
const HeaderText = ({ needsBackButton }) => {
  if(needsBackButton) {
    return (
       <View style={[styles.headerStyle,styles.buttonHeaderStyle]}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()} style={styles.backButtonStyles}><Icon.Ionicons size={25} style={{ color: '#fff', fontWeight: 'bold' }} name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? `ios-arrow-back` : 'md-arrow-back'} /></TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{this.props.headerText}</Text>
            <View style={styles.emptyViewStyles} />
        </View>
    )
  }
  return (
    // another component
  )
}
```

And then, You can simply use `useNavigation()` to access navigation prop from any screen/component.

First, import `useNavigation` on component that handled function of the moving screen.

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

Create some constant to reference this module:

```
const navigation = useNavigation()
```

And then, simply use this on your `TouchableOpacity`'s `onPress` prop like this;

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
  style={styles.backButtonStyles}
>
  //...
</ TouchableOpacity>
```

Get the complete documentation on this:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/connecting-navigation-prop/