# React Native Navigation between functional components?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am trying to navigate to the Main screen when Login button is pressed in Login.js. LoginForm loads perfectly but when I press the button I start receiving the error "TypeError: Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate'). Before this was not a problem but it changed when I moved Login to a different component. I was getting a different error and I went through this but it didn't fix it: [Getting undefined is not an object evaluating _this.props.navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45226391/getting-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-this-props-navigation)
Let me know if you need the whole code. Thanks :)

**LoginForm.js**

```
...
import Login from "./Login";

const LoginForm = props => {
  return <Login />
}
...
```

**Login.js**

```
const Login = ({ navigation }) => {
 return (
  <TouchableOpacity
    style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
    activeOpacity={1}
    onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Main")}
  >
    <View style={styles.loginButtonContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.loginButtonText}>Login</Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  )}
...
```

Comment: When you `console.log(navigation)` above the return what does it log ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it thanks to withNavigation. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html

> **withNavigation** is a higher order component which passes the navigation
>   prop into a wrapped component. It's useful when you cannot pass the
>   navigation prop into the component directly, or don't want to pass it
>   in case of a deeply nested child.

Login.js

```
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation'

const Login = ({ navigation }) => {
...
}

export default withNavigation(Login)
```

Anyway, if its possible, I would love to know how to fix it without this.