# How to do a routing inside a function? this function was getting an error in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

**Function :**

```
  async function ridirect(APIresponse) {
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
if(APIresponse.success == true){
  navigate('HomeBottomBar')

}
}
```

this function was getting error.

Comment: What was the error message? What does your navigation config look like?

Comment: [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation')

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45226391/getting-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-this-props-navigation

Answer (score 0):

It's you're not passing the navigation prop to the component. You could use [Navigation Context](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-context) to pass navigation to the function.

E.g.:

```
import { NavigationContext } from '@react-navigation/native';

async function ridirect(APIresponse) {
  const contextType = NavigationContext;;
  if(APIresponse.success == true){
    navigate('HomeBottomBar')
  }
}
```