# Is there any way I can control if a dumb component should re-render or not?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Is there any way I can control if a dumb component should re-render or not?

I know I can use `shouldComponentUpdate` for smart components which are class objects, but I want to know if I can do something similar to that for a dumb component.

Comment: make your dumb component extend react component class & override the shouldComponentUpdate function, unless your making stateless functional child components.

Comment: I want to make it a stateless functional component. I guess I should let the parent component decide if the child component should render or not and pass prop like 'shouldXXXUpdate' to it.

Comment: Components can be defined in three ways, stateless functions, pure components(shallow compare) or simple react components. Simple react components are also dumb components when they receive props from smart parent component and are not connected to the redux store. Stateless functions give less control over rendering and might have a performance edge. Extending simple react component instead of stateless function will allow u to override shouldComponentUpdate function in child and stay disconnected from the store. This thread will help u.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40703675/react-functional-stateless-component-purecomponent-component-what-are-the-dif.  sorry comment limits