# Is state the only difference between a PureComponent and a stateless functional component?

Tags: reactjs

If I define a `PureComponent` that

- only has a `render()` method, and
- does not use `this.state`,

...is it effectively identical to a stateless functional component? Or are there any differences in behaviour or performance?

This is not a duplicate of [React functional stateless component, PureComponent, Component; what are the differences and when should we use what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40703675) because the answer to my question is not contained there, at least not in a way that's easy to pinpoint. That is a big, wide-ranging question, and mine is very specific.

Answer (score 1):

A stateless functional component is effectively identical to `React.Component` without lifecycle methods and state, not to `React.PureComponent`.

The whole point of `React.PureComponent` is to use one of the life cycle methods (`shouldComponentUpdate`) and make it to return `true` only if properties & state have changed, using shallow comparison.

There is no way how to do that in stateless functional components since they are always rendered and have no way to define `shouldComponentUpdate`.

This behavior is described in detail in [Optimizing Performance](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html).