# ReactJS functionnal or pure for stateless components?

Tags: reactjs

What is the best between functionnal component and PureComponent when it's a stateless component ?

This :

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Example(props){
  return (
    <div>
      {props.myProps}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Or this :

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Example extends React.PureComponent {

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {this.props.myProps}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: useful link maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40703675/react-functional-stateless-component-purecomponent-component-what-are-the-dif

Comment: More or less but thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When its a stateless component, and you are not using shouldComponentUpdate() or any lifecycle methods, then you should go with functional components as this will be light weight than PureComponents.

Comment: I need some answer like that. Thx !!

Comment: Pls accept the answer too for the stack over flow community

Answer (score 0):

Functional components are more of building blocks and easy to reason about and can be/should be composed to make more complex components. And as per React docs, they might be able to enhance the performance of Functional components in future.

Pure Component is just a regular component with a syntactic sugar around props check in case one needs to implement shouldComponentUpdate based on props check; with Pure components you get that by default.