# React memo with stateless component

Tags: reactjs

Before react introduce `memo` and `hook` All functional component was stateless.

After Introducing `memo` and `hook` I'm little confused with these two concept.

Is `React.memo` for functions that use hook **only**?

Should I **update** all my stateless functional component to `React.memo` for optimizing? Or react optimize it when a function does not use hook automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For understanding what [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) is used for, first you have to understand the difference between [`React.Component`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactcomponent) and [`React.PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent).

From the docs -

> The difference between them is that React.Component doesn’t implement
>   shouldComponentUpdate(), but React.PureComponent implements it with a
>   shallow prop and state comparison.
>
> If your React component’s render() function renders the same result
>   given the same props and state, you can use React.PureComponent for a
>   performance boost in some cases.

`React.memo` is the same as a `React.PureComponent`, just for the functional components. So, if you think that with a given props, your component will be rendered the same, you can wrap your component with `React.memo` for performance boost and memoizing the result as mentioned [in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo).

But do specifically take a look at the line in the docs, which says -

> This method only exists as a performance optimization. Do not rely on
>   it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs.

And you should make your decision about using `React.memo` irrespective of the `hooks`.

Comment: before these release I use stateless function for optimizing instead of `Purecomponent`  because `component’s render() function renders the same result given the same props`. And If `React.memo` use for prevent re-render, So in the past PureComponent was better that function component?

Comment: Better - subjective. Useful in situations where a component renders the same with the same props - yes, as it's more performant.

Comment: Why not better? Purecomponent doest not re-render, and functional compoenent before this release should re-render if props changes. so in this scenario in the past should I use PureComponent? because there is no memo

Comment: As I said, better is subjective because of the line in the documentation - "This method only exists as a performance optimization. Do not rely on it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs." In your case, if you use it as a way to prevent render, it can introduce bugs.

Comment: I mean in the past, before memo, Is pure component better ( in optimizing ) than functional component? ( in this scenario: same props->same result ) and now react introduce memo to try solve this?

Comment: If you consider the optimization bit, then yes, again - only in the conditon where the render is same with the same props. So, just to make that optimization available with the functional components, `React.memo` was introduced. I love this post which has an elaborate discussion - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40703675/react-functional-stateless-component-purecomponent-component-what-are-the-dif